# Testing UI-bootstrap-alert with protractor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium-webdriver, protractor, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am trying to use protractor to test that my alerts are displayed correctly. Here is one of my spec files.

the HTML Code looks like

```
<div class="alert ng-scope floater bottom left fadeZoomFadeDown alert-success" 
ng-class="[type ? 'alert-' + type : null]" 
style="display: block;"><!-- ngIf: dismissable -->
  <button type="button" class="close ng-scope" ng-if="dismissable" ng-click="$hide()">
  </button><!-- end ngIf: dismissable --> <strong ng-bind="title" class="ng-binding"></strong>&nbsp;
 <span ng-bind-html="content" class="ng-binding">Test Person added successfully. </span>
</div>
```

the spec.js file for this alert

```
it('should be able to add a person to the person list from the list person view', function() {
    element(by.linkText('Persons')).click();
    personsUrl = browser.getCurrentUrl();

    count = element.all(by.repeater('person in persons')).length;
    element(by.linkText('Add Person')).click();
    element(by.id('person.firstName')).sendKeys('Test Person');

    //After adding person return to the persons list view.
    var alertElement = element(by.css('.alert-success'));
    element(by.buttonText('Add Person')).click().then(function(){
        expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toEqual(personsUrl);
        browser.wait(protractor.ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(alertElement), 10000) //Wait for 10 seconds until alert is visible
        .then(function(){ 
             expect(alertElement.isDisplayed()).toBe(true);
        });
    });
});
```

The terminal is returning an error saying "Failed: No element found using locator: By.cssSelector(".alert-success")", but when I manually test and I pause the browser, I can inspect the alert and see that it has several classes, and alert-success is definitely one of them. I just don't understand what I am doing wrong.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

I suppose the alert wouldn't be visible immediately and won't be on the DOM all the time. So you have to wait until its visible and then perform operations on it. Here's how -

```
var alertElement = element(by.css('.alert-success'));
element(by.buttonText('Add Tenant')).click().then(function(){
    browser.wait(protractor.ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(alertElement), 10000) //Wait for 10 seconds until alert is visible
    .then(function(){ 
         expect(alertElement.isDisplayed()).toBe(true);
         //Other operations on alert
    });
});
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes its better to put it inside the promise that `click()` function returns. However that's not completely necessary as protractor internally handles the promises in the form of Q, but it can avoid most of the errors you might face. Updated code with the same.

Comment: Hey Girish I am now getting a  Failed: Wait timed out after 10102ms error. Should I change the conf.js file to have $interval instead of $timeout? I have been hearing that is a work around for a lot of issues in protractor.

Comment: Are you sure that you are getting the proper element? Can you update your html code in the question? adding interval just increases your wait time and wouldn't benefit unless you are getting the alert within time specified. Thanks

Comment: updated the HTML code i see alert-success as a class

Comment: One more test, can you check if the alert is showing up on the screen when the script runs? Or does the alert not show up at all until the script fails? Thanks

Comment: I see that it displays right away and the script then starts to wait for the 10 seconds and then throws the failure and then starts to execute the rest of the script

Comment: Maybe I should have mentioned before that upon clicking the add button the url changes states and then the alert pops up. Maybe that is what is causing all my headache today

Comment: if you are using `dismiss-on-timeout` there are additional concerns to be aware of, see my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/38112240/3344695

Answer (score 1):

One issue with testing `<uib-alert>` : if you use the `dismiss-on-timeout` attribute then protractor will detect the timeout as an outstanding action and it will not evaluate any further expressions until the timeout elapses. And once the timeout elapses, the `<uib-alert>` dissappears !

NB this example is for angular 1.5 and protractor 3.3.0

Given a DOM element

```
<uib-alert id="successAlert" type="success" close="$ctrl.closeAlert('success')" dismiss-on-timeout="{{$ctrl.alertTimeout}}">Success - You are great, good job!</uib-alert>
```

This browser.wait block will not work (it will timeout):

```
doSomethingToMakeTheAlertDisplay();

browser.wait(protractor.ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(this.successAlert), 15000).then( function(result) {
  console.log("browser.wait is done waiting");
  return result;
})
```

But if you disable syncronization and then re-enable it then the browser.wait will work

```
doSomethingToMakeTheAlertDisplay();

browser.ignoreSyncronization = true;

browser.wait(protractor.ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(this.successAlert), 15000).then( function(result) {
  browser.ignoreSyncronization = false;
  console.log("browser.wait is done waiting");
  return result;
})
```

The underlying issue is captured here : https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/169